# How to set a ratio to select the payment method from multiple payment methods in laravel

Tags: laravel

Consider we have an "orders" table and have multiple payment gateways.
We now have a need where we will be setting ratio for each payment gateway.
For example if we have a ratio set to 2:1, every 2 orders should be given gateway "x" and 1 order should be assigned to gateway "y".

I need to develop a mechanism, in which user can set the ratio against each payment gateway. This ratio should become functional as soon as the user sets it.

PaymentGateway and Orders table is in a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: why would you want to do that ?

Comment: How are payment gateways and orders in one to one relationship? Can't a payment gateway handle multiple orders? Anyway it seems you need to implement weighted round robin algorithm here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_round_robin. I hope, you will find many implementions in PHP.

Comment: Dear @AbdullahAlFarooq no, each order needs to have a single payment gateway. I need to have a setup in the backend so each user can only see one payment option at a time as defined in the retio.

Comment: @HassaanAli I need to set a restriction to show the end-user a single payment gateway as per the set ratio.

Comment: @SaleemJafar do you have different payment gateways for different orders, say you have 1000 orders, so do you also have 1000 payment gateways?

Comment: @AbdullahAlFarooq, no payment gateways can be up to 5 max

Comment: @SaleemJafar Okay, so now what you need to do, implement a weighted round robin algorithm and set the payment gateway of each order using that algorithm. There are many but I found this one, https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/round-robin-weight-round-robin-algorithm-php-implementation-code-_php-skills_1_34_20128051.html You need to update it for your need.